# Join the name of the columns in comma-sperated format whilst parsing the table with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse the columns and rows of the timetable and then have it in a CSV file to import it to my google calendar.

So I when I try to get the title of the columns for perhaps any data from the column it comes one under another (refer the pic below.)
[[image: out of the code on terminal1]

the code for the above output can be found below.

```
const columnTitles = $('.spreadsheet .spreadsheet .columnTitles')
.each((i, element)=> {
  const nameLabel = $(element).text().trimStart().trimEnd();
  console.log(nameLabel );
})
```

Below is the screenshot of HTML Elements
[image]

What am I missing on here? and how can I have it as comma-separated-values?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one table, then it's simple:

```js
var html_table = $('.spreadsheet .spreadsheet .columnTitles');
var table_header = html_table.find('td').map(function() {return $(this).text().trim();}).toArray();
console.log('table_header', table_header.join(', '));
```